# How to transform coordinates to location in x-y grid in R?

Tags: r, coordinate-system, coordinates

I have a polygon with a 40m diameter and several points that lay inside it. Now I want to reformat the point locations (projected in DHDN/GK-3, but could vary) to x-y coordinates ranging from zero to the maximal diameter of the polygon (in this case 40m).

I am working in R and therefore I need a scripted solution.

Pictures say more than words:
The triangle is the polygons centroid. The green dots the point locations.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right: it is a simple algebra calculation. You have two cartesian coordinate systems.

For the x-coordinate of the blue point:
20 + 2500117 - 2500100 = 37

[image]

This solution works only if the coordinate system is a "projected coordinate system" (e.G. Gauss-Krueger, UTM, ...). It is not a solution for "geographical coordinate systems" (e.g. WGS84).

Comment: no comment. Thanks for this easy solution ;-) However it results in some negative values, which is why i took the diameter instead of the radius. I should read some of those old highschool math books...

Answer (score 0):

There is Proj4 library interface for R in CRAN http://cran.r-project.org/package=proj4 and http://www.rforge.net/proj4/
After that only thing what you need is source and destination SRID

Comment: I don't want to transform between projections, but instead from one projection to a cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: A projection can be either **geographic** or **projected**. In the first case, your coordinates are in the φ,λ (spherical) plane and in the later  in x,y (Cartesian) plane.

Comment: proj4 **can** solve your problem. You need create a custom proj4 string, with the appropriate parameters. http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms .

Comment: Ahh. i understood question wrong  and assumed that we were talking about point on globe. But still you can solve problem with proj4 using link 'nickves' provided